# root user cannot do any change on files because of files are readonly

Tags: linux, read-only

Maybe the solution is too basic but i cannot do any change on files as root because files opens as readonly. Because I booted the operating system from readonly snapshot.

The reason of this situation is this. Files under /etc are readonly. How can I return to read-writable filesystem from readonly?

Operating System: SLES 12 (image not belong to me)

When I open /etc/resolv.conf with vim as root, bottom line of file is like this:

```
"/etc/resolv.conf" [readonly] 23L, 870C
```

and if I enter insert mode:

```
-- INSERT -- W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file
```

Comment: If the file system is read only that is kind of expected. Perhaps you should copy them to a `rw` file system?

Comment: i think there is another way that not need new rw filesystem. I booted the os from snapshot and i cannot find a way mount /etc as rw. But at the other hand, at our other SLES machines /etc is not shown mount list. But i can do change on this machine's etc files.

Comment: i found the way. its just two words but finding this was too hard.

Comment: Nice to see you added an answer. Please set it as solution. Also, both question ans answer are hard to understand.

Comment: I changed the question. Question is the same but it's now more clear, i think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way.

After boot from snapshot run below command as root:

```
snapper rollback
```

This command allows to rollback from snapshot that machine runs on.

So, because of this is a snapshot, if you rollback from this, **you may lose your data**.